# Is the path for importing modules different on different operating systems?

Tags: python, spyder

I have a python project in spyder that I work on no matter where I am, which means that I open it and work on it on Mac, Windows, and Ubuntu all within a day.  The problem is importing modules never works the same on windows.

I have the file system set up as follows:

```
- /Project
    * Main.py
- /modules
    * Functions.py
    * constants.py
    * otherFunctions.py
- /Data
    * bunch of data files
```

in Main.py, I have:

```
import modules.Functions as gf
import modules.otherFunctions as of
from modules.constants import gas_const_R, Solar_const
```

Inside otherFunctions.py, I have:

```
import modules.Functions as gf
```

In constants.py, I have:

```
gas_const_R = 287.04
Solar_const = 1368.0
```

This all works perfectly on Linux and Mac, but Windows will not import the constants and it won't let otherFunctions.py import Functions.py.

The current working directory is the same on all OS's.  Main.py can import all modules, but they cannot import each other on Windows, and I can't get the constants on Windows.

Is this a problem in my spyder settings?
Is it a problem with the windows path?
Is there a way I can import differently depending on which operating system I am on?

Comment: what python version are you on? (you also should remove `.py` from the import statement)

Comment: `modules.constants.py` seem incorrect (the `.py` extension shouldn't be there).

Comment: It's not on there in my code, I made a typo in the question.  Thanks, I will fix that.

Comment: What do you mean with 'will not import'? Does it throw an error message? If yes, which? If no, what fails?

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name 'gas_const_R'

Comment: @TattonChantry That error would indicate that is actually found the constants module, but the name `gas_const_R` was not defined in there. Are you sure the contents (Including upper/lower-case are correct)?

Comment: @MegaIng yes, because it works on Linux and Mac, and if I copy paste those constants into Main.py it works, which is the work-around I have been using.

Comment: Can you create a github repository/a zip file with a [mcve] of this problem? And the full error message you are getting?

Comment: @MegaIng https://github.com/tattonchantry/Ice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on how your IDE is executing your program, specifically, what your CWD (current working directory) is. That is where (some) imports are made relative to. You can check what this directory is by running:

```
import os
print(os.path.abspath('.')
```

For the behavior you want, this should print the parent directory of all three directories. If it doesn't, you have to change the settings of your IDE (sorry, I don't know spyder).

Comment: It is .../Project on all operating systems.  I can import /Data and all the modules from Main.py, But they cannot import each other on Windows.

Comment: @TattonChantry what does `print(sys.path)` output? is `'.'` in there?

Comment: No, it's not. Should it be?

Comment: @TattonChantry In some sense, yes, in some sense no. Forget it, My mistake. Is the parent directory in there?

Comment: Yes, the parent directory is there on both Windows and Linux.  Neither have '.'